# How to be notified of connection created/closed to Apache ActiveMQ broker

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic

I would like my Java application to observe Apache ActiveMQ broker and be informed of new created and closed connections

I searched classes in `org.apache.activemq` package and subpackage but unfortunately I didn't find anything for that.

Answer (score 2):

You can listen on new and closed connection events through [ActiveMQ Advisory Topics](https://activemq.apache.org/advisory-message). Advisory topics can be subscribed to and you can receive advisory messages on the following events (from that page):

- consumers, producers and connections starting and stopping
- temporary destinations being created and destroyed
- messages expiring on topics and queues
- brokers sending messages to destinations with no consumers.
- connections starting and stopping

Comment: Thank you. Indeed, I did a few tests using topic ``CONNECTION_ADVISORY_TOPIC`` (cf. ``org.apache.activemq.advisory.AdvisorySupport``) and it seems to provide exactly what I was looking for